# KKT conditions for non-differentiable constraints

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, karush-kuhn-tucker, subgradient

So I know that for the problem:

$$
\begin{align*}
\text{minimize} \quad & f_0(x) \\
\text{subject to} \quad & f_i(x) \leq 0, \quad i = 1, 2, \ldots, m \\
\end{align*}
$$

We have the following necessary sufficient KKT conditions, when we assume strong duality, and that the problem is convex.

$$
\begin{align}
\nabla_x \mathcal{L}(x^*, \lambda^*) &= 0 \\
\lambda_i^* f_i(x^*) &= 0, \quad i = 1, 2, \ldots, m \\
\lambda_i^* &\geq 0, \quad i = 1, 2, \ldots, m
\end{align}
$$

Where:

$$
\mathcal{L}(x, \lambda) := f_0(x) + \sum_{i=1}^m \lambda_i f_i(x)
$$

---

I have seen in a few places that this can be generalised for problems where the constraints are non-differentiable. For example, the Lasso problem, which has $L_1$ constraints.
But I want an exact description of the conditions, for the **non-differentiable case**.

Is the gradient in the following KKT condition replaced with a sub-differential?

\begin{align}
\nabla_x \mathcal{L}(x^*, \lambda^*) &= 0
\end{align}

Any references would be useful, with pointers to the exact place in those references.
So far been trying to look in [Nonlinear Optimization by Andrzej Ruszczynski](https://press.princeton.edu/books/hardcover/9780691119151/nonlinear-optimization)

Comment: For the stationarity condition of the KKT conditions, yes, one could replace gradients with subdifferentials, see, e.g., slide#7: https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~ggordon/10725-F12/slides/16-kkt.pdf

Comment: @user550103 Thank you for these slides. So, assuming strong duality, the KKT conditions, with the gradient in the stationary condition replaced by a subdifferential, are necessary. Then, assuming convexity, the conditions are sufficient. On slide 10 they did not make it explicit that we require the assumption that the primal problem is convex, but this is needed right? As in order for the stationary condition to imply that $x^* $ minimises the lagrangian?